# BitcoinCore cant load wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I have retrieved an old wallet.dat file from my harddrive that crashed about 5 years ago.

I have downloaded the new version of bitcoincore and downloaded the blockchain. I have then copied the wallet.dat file (which is in 96 kb) into the directory where the wallet should be.

But when i try to open the wallet.dat i get this sign: "Warning: Skipping -wallet path that doesn't exist. Failed to load database path'E:\bitcoin\wallet1.dat'. Path does not exist.

It says E because i had to download the blockchain on a separate hdd.

What could the issue be? I have tried to make new wallets and open them from the same directory and that has not been a problem. Can i somehow open the wallet to retrieve the private keys??

Answer (score 2):

tldr: specify a directory not a file and have that folder contain a `wallet.dat` not a `wallet1.dat`.

---

Your error message said

> ```
>  Warning: Skipping -wallet path that doesn't exist. 
>  Failed to load database path'E:\bitcoin\wallet1.dat'. Path does not exist.
> ```

However the help for the program says

> `-wallet=<path>`
> Specify wallet path to load at startup. Can be used multiple times to load multiple wallets. **Path is to a directory** containing wallet data and log files. If the path is not absolute, it is interpreted relative to <walletdir>. This only loads existing wallets and does not create new ones. For backwards compatibility this also accepts names of existing top-level data files in <walletdir>.

(My emphasis).

An example configuration file says

```
# Specify where to find wallet, lockfile and logs. If not present, those files 
# will be created as new.
# wallet=</path/to/dir>
```

Your `E:\bitcoin\wallet1.dat` is a file not a directory

I can reproduce something similar by copying a valid wallet.dat to wallet1.data in a separate folder with no other Bitcoin files in it

```
C:> bitcoin-qt -wallet=c:\Users\ZZZ\Documents\wallet1.dat
```

[image: Error message]

So I think you could

- rename `wallet1.dat` to `wallet.dat`
- specify `E:\bitcoin\` not `E:\bitcoin\wallet1.dat`.

Comment: Thank you. That is somehow confusing since the wallet.dat file in the is not named ”wallet1.dat”. After this message, btq opens without a wallet. What is more confusing is that the other wallet.dat filés are able to open in a way this particular one does not. The wallet.dat is in a folder with bitcoin files in it, and the other wallets do open when i run then from the same path. Now what could i do to retrieve the private keys?